# java.lang.IllegalStateException: IJ000152: Trying to return an unknown connection: org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk7.WrappedConnectionJDK7@50d81342

Tags: jakarta-ee, transactions, ejb, illegalstateexception

I have EJB beans

```
@Stateless
public class ClientFacadeBean implements IClient {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "BDModel")
    private EntityManager em;

    @EJB(lookup = "java:global/services-1.0.5/api.ejb-1.1/ConsoleLogFacadeBean!by.api.IConsoleLog")
    IConsoleLog iConsoleLog;

    @Override
    public Response getClients(String sessionId, ClientFilter clientFilter) {
...
            iConsoleLog.writeLog(sessionId, "message", clientFilter);

...
    }
}

@Stateless
public class ConsoleLogFacadeBean implements IConsoleLog {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "BDModel")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public void writeLog(String session, String message) {
...
    }
}
```

I get data, but also get warning

```
15:59:39,701 INFO  [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener] (default task-14) IJ000311: Throwable from unregister connection: java.lang.IllegalStateException: IJ000152: Trying to return an unknown connection: org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk7.WrappedConnectionJDK7@50d81342
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.ccm.CachedConnectionManagerImpl.unregisterConnection(CachedConnectionManagerImpl.java:408)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener.connectionClosed(TxConnectionListener.java:645)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.BaseWrapperManagedConnection.returnHandle(BaseWrapperManagedConnection.java:596)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.BaseWrapperManagedConnection.closeHandle(BaseWrapperManagedConnection.java:541)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection.returnConnection(WrappedConnection.java:298)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection.close(WrappedConnection.java:256)
```

If you give the bean a ConsoleLogFacadeBean annotation @TransactionAttribute (TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
That works without warnings

What is the correct TransactionAttribute should be in ConsoleLogFacadeBean
Or to alter, that private **EntityManager em** was common for all beans